# Как вывести рубрики на страницу Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, вывод

И так [сам сайт создан на WP](http://1.santehniki.pp.ua/stati) создал рубрику статьи которая отображает полностью все написанные статьи, но как вывести рубрики на страницу. Как на скришоте [image: вывод рубрик на сайт wordpress]
Тема вордпресс modality/ не имеет файла function.php и не имеет файла архив как таковой
Подскажите куда копать? Вот создана страница, вставлен шорт код который выводит записи, как сделать так же без плагина и добавлением виджетов на страницу

Comment: На картинке - справа sidebar, а в нем widget (если это WP). Чем вам виджеты не угодили? Widgets - стандартный функционал WP. Вы хотите использовать WordPress без функционала WordPress?

Comment: Для начала определите в каком шаблоне выводятся ваши статьи, потом используя WP_Query задайте необходимые параметры

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен вывод всех постов на главной, можно использовать основной цикл WP. И как рекомендация, для вывода постов используйте отдельные файлы.

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ){
        while ( have_posts() ){ the_post();
            get_template_part( 'post-template', get_post_format() );
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Записей не обнаружено.';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Копайте в этом направлении

```
<?php 

  $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'stati',
    'posts_per_page' => 6
  );

  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php } ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```